# Stop horizontal Scrolling in a react app on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The issue I am having is that when I open the website on mobile it has a horizontal scroll to a bunch of white space that looks really bad. I want to disable horizontal scrolling. There should be no white space on the right side of the screen as well.

I have tried numerous .css solutions I have read about, such as:

```
width:100vw;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

I also tried

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I also added a red boarder to see where the element was that was causing the problem and it was below the footer on some pages, but simply not visible on others.

[image]

There are two files and App.js file and App.css file, which I included below.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './contact.css'

const navbarFont = {
    fontFamily: "Times-Italic", // Replace with any system font you prefer
  };

const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <div className = 'Contact-header' style={navbarFont}>
        <h1 style={navbarFont}>
            Contact
        </h1>
        <div className='Contact-content'>
        <p className = 'Contact'>
          <div>
          Call us.
          </div>
        <p className='Contact-content' text-align ='center'>
            _____________________
        </p>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer" style={navbarFont}>
                <p>
                    <div>____________________</div>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>

    );
};

export default Contact;
```

App.css

```
.Contact {
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.Contact-header {
  position:relative;
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: gray;
}


.footer {
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.footer p {
  color: white;
}

/* Add flex styles to create a sticky footer */
.Contact-content {
  flex: 1; /* Make the content section take the remaining space and push the footer to the bottom */
}
```

The goal is to get rid of all horizontal scrolling on the application. How can I stop all horizontal scrolling?

Comment: seems it's the `width: 100vw` in `.footer` that is the culprit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just changed it to `max-width:100vw;` in `.footer` however, the white space on the right and scroll bar are still there.

Comment: I never suggested a change of property - try removing

Comment: I see. Thank you. Removing did not work either.

Comment: I added a bug report on GitHub. [Bug: horizontal scroll to bad white space on mobile version of application #27143](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/27143)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the index.html file. The viewport should be changed as such:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```